# Python while loop and Reeborg's World Challenge

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to solve *Hurdle 4* for challange from https://reeborg.ca/reeborg.html -
Using Python, mainly while loops.

While below code works perfect for the challange:

```
def turn_right():
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
    
def pass_the_wall():
    turn_left()
    while wall_on_right():
        move()
    turn_right()
    move()
    turn_right()
    while front_is_clear():
        move()
    turn_left()      
    
while not at_goal():
    if wall_in_front():
        pass_the_wall()
    else:
        move()
```

I have written something like this:

```
def turn_right():
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
    

def pass_the_wall():
    if front_is_clear():
        move()
    if wall_in_front():
        turn_left()
        while wall_on_right():
            move()
            while right_is_clear():
                turn_right()
                move()
                turn_right()
                move()
            while wall_in_front():
                turn_left()
                
while not at_goal():
    if wall_in_front():
        pass_the_wall()
    else:
        move()
```

It can follow the path, but the Reeborg does not stop as loop is infinite.

I have a feeling, that it may work this way, but I've lost logic here and need some fress outlook.

Question is where I have made a mistake? Is there a way to not change my code and only add some lines, that will stop the loop.

I tried *continue* and *break* - not working here.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
if at_goal():
    done()
```

Right after one of your `move()`s.

Which one? I'll leave it to you to find out

Edit: Okay, after TWO of your `move()`s

Answer (score 1):

i think this my code optimize than your:

```
def follow_right_wall():
    if right_is_clear():
        turn_right()
        move()
    elif front_is_clear():
        move()
    else:
        turn_left()            
think(0)
while not at_goal():
    follow_right_wall()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
def turn_right():
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
    turn_left()

def action():
    if front_is_clear():
        move()
    elif wall_in_front():
        turn_left()
        while not right_is_clear():
            move()
        turn_right()
        move()
        turn_right()
        while not wall_in_front():
            move()
        turn_left()

while not at_goal():
    action()
```

Comment: Welcome. This was a contest / assignment. Please take extra care to add explanations on how your answer solves the problem. About homework questions: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12846804)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).